# SciPy Curve Fit Wrong Covarience Calculation

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit my data with modified powerlaw function. Everything looks fine, but when I run it it gives wrong covariants and wrong fit. Curve is not fitting between first data point to last data point.
Yo can download data from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6c0e-DwluM5NnBJTHUwbFdub2M/view?usp=sharing). My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from __future__ import division

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit




pff = pd.read_csv('/home/foo/file.csv', sep=',', encoding ='utf-8')


pf = pff.sort_values(by= ['MJDMEAN'], ascending=1).reset_index()


fig = plt.figure()
xx = pf['MJDMEANMAX'].max()
x_lim = pf['MJDMEAN']-xx  ##values are quite big. so, I'm normalizing the values.


###############################
b1 = pf['LUMINOSITYMAX'].max()/pf['LUMINOSITY'].min() #normalization for luminosity




xx = pf['MJDMEANMAX'].max()
xi = pf["MJDMEAN"]
x = xi-xx
yi = pf['LUMINOSITY']
y = yi/pf['LUMINOSITY'].min()#normalization for luminosity




b1_1 = np.argmax(y)

b1_2 =  y[b1_1:]
x_new = x[b1_1:]


#here is the fit function.

def h(x1,k):
    return b1*((x1+k)/k)**(-1.67)


# calculation of the fit parameters.
popt,pcov = curve_fit(h,x_new,b1_2,bounds = (9,1001))#



x_noisy = np.linspace(x_new.max(),x_new.min(),10)

y_fi1 =pf['LUMINOSITY'].min()*(h(x_noisy, *popt))

y_ax4_1 = pf['LUMINOSITYUP'].abs()

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax4.plot(x_noisy, y_fi1, label='fit', ls='-', color='blue')
ax4.errorbar(x,y*pf['LUMINOSITY'].min() , yerr = pf['LUMINOSITY_ERR'],ls='None', color='blue', marker='o')


plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

And output is:

[image: Curve fit]

Here are the fit parameters:

```
POPT, [ 236.7885898] PCOV [[ 13393.26774051]]
```

New y data:

```
Y FIT [  1.50943124e+42   1.80062384e+42   2.19326494e+42 2.74315721e+42 3.55197127e+42   4.82266595e+42   7.01463975e+42 1.13794048e+43 2.25493405e+43   7.32406020e+43]
```

What am I missing? It calculates covariances and new y datas very wrong. Should I give some initial guess for pcov? Also, could Pandas be the source of the problem?

Comment: Why didn't you include `sigma=pf['LUMINOSITY_ERR'], absolute_sigma=True` inside `curve_fit`?

Comment: Actually, this is a another problem I have. When I put `sigma=pf['LUMINOSITY_ERR'], absolute_sigma=True` inside the `curve_fit` I'm having this error:     `raise ValueError("Residuals are not finite in the initial point.")
ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point.` I'm going to be a crazy...

Comment: Strange. I get no error when using it.

Comment: Really? Are you using `bounds` too?

Comment: Yes, but i m on  python3. Might be relevant, don't know; haven't looked up the Value error you mentioned.

Comment: I change the environment as a `python3`, it worked but, now it's calculates covariance very very wrong...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134519/discussion-between-anniejcannon-and-fermi-paradox).